# Spring Cloud Gateway Session Sharing via Redis

Tags: spring-boot, session, redis, spring-cloud-gateway

I am running a Spring Cloud Gateway service which does authentication and authorization and serves as a BFF (Backend-For-Frontend) in a landscape of a dozen services.
The problem is that if I restart this service (or just scale it out - it runs on a k8s cluster) the users that were already logged on lose the session and get kicked out.

I know with SpringBoot WebMVC apps I can use redis to persist the session and share it with other services, but Spring Cloud Gateway seems to not work using the same dependencies.

How do I share the session among different Spring Cloud Gateway instances?